# merge 2 queries in Javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have 2 queries:

1. `var x = ['mike',20];`
2. `var y = ['steve',25];`

How do I combine it into:

```
['mike',20],['steve',25];
```

without using blockquote?

So, I have a problem when calling a value, at Highcharts, I can't repeat it in highcharts, so I'm looking for a solution to combine 2 different variables, but still fail. About blockquote, if I call a variable flanked by blockquote, the code fails.can u help me?

I can't repeat in the code below

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser share',
    data: [
        ['Firefox', 41.0],
        ['IE', 26.8],
        {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 12.8,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
        },
        ['Safari', 8.5],
        ['Opera', 6.2],
        ['Others', 0.7]
    ]
}]
```

especially in part data

update

I run the code above in:

```
$.post("proses.php",function(data){
  //the code is he
},"json");
```

so i can show value from database,How to do it?

Comment: Those are two *arrays*. Do you just mean an array of arrays (a *"multidemensional array"*), like `var z = [x,y]`? What is the significance of blockquote?

Comment: You mean [x,y].join(',') ??
result : "mike,20,steve,25"

Comment: So, I have a problem when calling a value, at Highcharts, I can't repeat it in highcharts, so I'm looking for a solution to combine 2 different variables, but still fail. About blockquote, if I call a variable flanked by blockquote, the code fails.can u help me?

Comment: `blockquote` is HTML, it has nothing to do with JavaScript. It's really not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: `variable.series.data.push(x)` will add `x` to the end of the `data` array.

Comment: this is unclear...  you mean : let xyz = {['mike',20],['steve',25] };   ?

Comment: @MrJ That would be incorrect, as you've used `{ ... }` (object) instead of `[ ... ]` (array).

Comment: @MrJ not let but var

Comment: @Tyler Roper, yes it is, as I seen JS object in his sample code => series: [{(

Comment: how can I do looping in the data?

Comment: @MrJ You can have an array of objects, like this `names: [ {name: "Tyler"}, {name: "MrJ"} ]`, as OP does in his example (although the array has only one object). Your example is syntactically incorrect, as you can't encapsulate a list of items with curly brackets - it isn't a valid object. It throws an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`.

Comment: @Tyler Roper, yes you said true, this  is syntactically incorrect  , this is just a question, not an answer and not even an example

Comment: I think @MrJ means `xyz = [['mike',20],['steve',25] ];`. But the OP already knows how to do 2-dimensional arrays, he already has that in `data`.

Answer (score 1):

is that what you want ?

(based on your message = how can I do looping in the **data**? )

```js
let js_info= 
    { series: 
      [ { type: 'pie', name: 'Browser share'
        , data: 
          [ [ 'Firefox', 41.0] 
          , [ 'IE'     , 26.8] 
          , { name: 'Chrome', y: 12.8, sliced: true, selected: true } 
          , [ 'Safari' , 8.5] 
          , [ 'Opera'  , 6.2]
          , [ 'Others' , 0.7] 
          ] 
        } 
      ] 
    }
let Query_1 = ['mike' ,20]
let Query_2 = ['steve',25]

js_info.series[0].data.push(Query_1, Query_2)

for (let elm of js_info.series[0].data)
  {
  if (Array.isArray(elm))
    { console.log( `name: '${elm[0]}' , y: ${elm[1]} ` ) }
  else
    { console.log( `name: '${elm.name}' , y: ${elm.y} ` ) }
  }
```

Comment: can the code above repeat the value of the database?
so that it can display different values

Comment: where does come from this DataBase ?
you never asked it before!
Could you be more clear to explain what ever you want to do ?

Comment: I edited it.....

Comment: jQuery Post is for sending data, and not for reading data...

Comment: In another case, I managed to read or send data, but in this case I failed

Comment: use jQuery.get() to read data from your server php who should acces to your database.

Comment: my problem it's was solved